# Making Javascript Code run on Page Start

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html

I need to run my JavaScript Code on Page Start.

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('Label1').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('Textbox1').style.display = 'none';">
```

Currently I'musing a Onload property in Body Tag and using the code in that. By using in this way the code is running after the total page is loaded and it takes some time to make the label and the textbox to disappear.

Is there any way to run this code before the page Loads??

Or some other way in which I can accomplish this ?

(I'm using another JavaScript function to make the Label and Textbox Visible and Invisible basing on a DropdownList SelectedIndex so if I use properties like style="display:none" I could not make them visible again using JavaScript)

Comment: You would be better off using the JQuery `$(function () {});` rather than using the on load method of the HTML body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make your html elements invisible with javascript when the page is being loaded. You can set them invisible with css using `visibility:hidden` or `display:none` and then set them visible with javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById("someobject").style.display="block";
OR
document.getElementById("someobject").style.visibility="visible";
```

Also if you are using jquery you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Comment: How can we make them visible using style="display:none" and set "display:block" with javascript??

Comment: Thank you @Rafael Sedrakyan. I've set the style="display:none" to the textbox & label and set document.getElementById("lbl_OtherProof").style.display = "block"; in JavaScript. I don't want to use JQuery for very minor things so I didn't try JQuery.

Comment: You're welcome. That is why I wrote "If you are using jquery" :)

Comment: Yep Gotcha. Thanks again. Bye

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery's `$(document).ready(function(){ this is my code; });`